# ASP.net MVC Table relationships

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, model, relation

I am new to ASP.net MVC and this is my first attempt at it. I designing a small site with relational tables. (to keep it short, I removed some irrelevant fields)

**`Items`**:

- `Id int (PK)`
- `description nvarchar(50)`
- `divisionid nchar(2) FK`
- `categoryid nchar(6) FK`

**`Division`**

- `code nchar(2) PK`
- `description nvarchar(50)`

**`Category`**

- `code nchar(6) PK`
- `description nvarchar(50)`

I believe is quite self explanatory. when trying to create the model below for it:

```
public class Item
{
    [Key]
    [Display(Name="Id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Description is required")]
    [Display(Name = "Description")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Description must not be more than 50 characters long")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Division")]
    [StringLength(2)]
    public string DivisionId { get; set; }        

    [Display(Name = "Category")]
    [StringLength(6)]        

    [ForeignKey("DivisionId")]
    public virtual Division division { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

}

public class Division
{
    [Key]
    [Display(Name = "Code")]
    [StringLength(2, ErrorMessage = "Code must be 2 char.")]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Description")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Description is required")]
    [StringLength(50,ErrorMessage="Description must not be more than 50 characters long")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    [Key]
    [Display(Name = "Code")]
    [StringLength(6, ErrorMessage = "Code must be 6 char.")]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Description")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Description is required")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Description must not be more than 50 characters long")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is when running the site, I get the exception invalid object name `dbo.Divisions`
with an error pointing at the return value in the controller

```
    Line 20:         {
    Line 21:             var items = db.Items.Include(i => i.division).Include(i => i.Category);
    Line 22:             return View(items.ToList());
    Line 23:         }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert on this, but maybe your table should be named "Divisions", i think plural form is expected in table names.